# jpa+spring+test,repository Class cant be found

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-data-jpa

i want to test the spring jpa but get 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personRepository';

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private int flag;
    private String source;
    //getters and setters ...
}


@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, AtomicInteger> {
    Person findByName(String name);
    Person findByCodeAndName();
    @Query("from Person p where p.name = :name")
    Person findUser(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

and my ConfigClass:need i costumized the @EnableJpaRepositories?

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"learn.jpaRepository"},
        basePackageClasses = {PersonRepository.class})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "learn.model")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "learn")
@SpringBootApplication
public class LearnConfig {
}
```

my application.properties in main/resources

```
    spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/learnspring
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

and my test class: every Class this Test need is in pom.xml

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = LearnConfig.class)
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFunctionConfig() {
        Person p = personRepository.findByName("clz");
        System.out.println(p.getName());
    }
}
```

i just get the error below:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: `findByCodeAndName` expects two parameters but none have been supplied to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring can't load PersonRepository because there are missing parameters in `findByCodeAndName` query method, change it to:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, AtomicInteger> {
    ...
    Person findByCodeAndName(String code, String name);
    ...
}
```

Comment: actually, i dont know what i have done,i try many times this afternoon,it worked!thanks for your answer,this method is also my fault